# How to call on a view when a Picker selection is selected

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have a `Picker` and when one of the selections is selected I'm trying to make it call on my camera view, but nothing happens. I tried to call on a function to make it print and that didn't work either. Here's the code

```
Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("Discover Plug")) {
    ForEach(vm.dataSet, id:\.self) { item in
        Text(item.Device).tag(item.Device)
    }.onTapGesture{
       //CameraView()
       //print("selected")
         Selected()
    }    
}

func Selected() {
        print("selected")
}
```

I've tried to moving `.onTapGesture` in different places and also tried putting the Text in a button but that didn't work, any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for solving your problem:

```
enum CameraEnum: String, CaseIterable { case telephoto, wide, ultraWide}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selection: CameraEnum = .wide
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker(selection: $selection, label: EmptyView(), content: {

            ForEach(CameraEnum.allCases, id:\.self) { item in
                
                Text(item.rawValue)
                
            }
 
        })
        .onAppear() { cameraFunction(selection) }
        .onChange(of: selection, perform: { value in cameraFunction(value) })
        
    }
    
    private func cameraFunction(_ cameraValue: CameraEnum) {
        print("Your camera selection is:", cameraValue)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: would this still work for bringing up the camera in a view instead of printing the selection? and if so, how would I go about the `enum` if I have it set up like this `struct deviceResults: Codable {
    let result:[Result]
}
struct Result: Codable, Hashable {
    let Device: String
}` because im decoding the selection items from a server

Comment: @LloydEnglish: You are new in this website, let explain that we are not mixing questions or issues together here! Also we are not hostage the answer and Bargaining about solving another issue once the first issue got solved! Your question was about use case of Picker and detecting the selection! My answer is a complete and simple one for your issue, for other questions make another question and simply accept this answer. PS: You can use your array instead of Enum as well! No problem there!